# Option from collection for select in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have custom `select_tag` with `options_from_collection_for_select`

```
= select_tag "[recipient_tokens]", options_from_collection_for_select(User.where(:id => params[:users]), :id, :email, params[:users]), :size => "#{params[:users].size}"
```

But I cant create this `select` with one value in `simple form`

Comment: What's your question?  Here's an example of a select list via Simple Form: `= f.association :sport, as: :select, collection: Sport.order(:name), prompt: "Choose a Sport", required: true`

Comment: @steakchaser Question is: how to create select field with only single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= f.input "[recipient_tokens]", collection: User.where(:id => params[:users]), label_method: 'email', include_blank: false
```